# Check if requested URL is a file in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the file structure of my site

---

```
/app/
    /controllers/
    /views/
    /lib/
    /public/
    .htaccess
```

---

I want to check if the requested URL is a ***file inside public dir***

I tried this inside the .htaccess

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

---

But this is not working. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try your check like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```